# Tomcat : WAR file is not deployed when starting in remote debugging

Tags: tomcat, jpda

I am starting tomcat in remote debugging via a .bat file that I have created which contains:

```
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.6
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
set PATH=%javahome%\bin;%PATH%
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
set JDPA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
%CATALINA_HOME%/bin/catalina.bat jpda start
```

Tomcat starts at localhost listening on port 8000.The issue is that it does not deploy any WAR files that put in the webapps folder. I tried to deploy the WAR file from the Tomcat Manager App but I am not able to log in even though I have defined an admin user in tomcat-user.xml file:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

If I start tomcat normally the WAR file gets deployed and I am also able to access Manager App with the credentials I specified above.

Comment: does catalina.out contain anything ?

Comment: No log files are created in %CATALINA_HOME%/Log folder when I start   the server for remote debugging. If I start the server normally, the logs are there.